# Getting more detailed Stack Exchange mails -- Part 1

Tags: html, css, html5

I made the layout for a new project which will allow you to subscribe to periodic emails about your favorite Stack Exchange site (I'm not very happy with the SE-provided one). Since I'm horrible at design and in essence new to HTML/CSS/Javascript, I figured I'd get started with that so the hard part is over.

Below is the HTML and CSS that make up the first draft of the layout. Before I get started making everything dynamic by incorporating AngularJS and NodeJS, I want to make sure that the HTML as I've written here follows best practices.

Suggestions concerning layout are very welcome as well. Did I mention I'm horrible at design?

One aspect I'm rather uneasy with is the way I layout things to the right-side of the screen: `direction: rtl`.

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif
}

#header {
  height: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border-radius: 1em;
}

#header ul {
  direction: rtl; 
}

#header li {
  padding-top: 1em;
    margin-right: 2em;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: right;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#header ul li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* don't make the separation markers clickable */
#header ul li:nth-child(2):hover {
  cursor: none;
}

#content {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 2em;
}

#intro {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2em;
}

#settings {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#siteSelector > ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#siteSelector > ul > li > p {
  float: left;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.selectedSite {
  border: 0.5em inset #ffc726;
}

#tagSelector  {
  clear: both;
}

.tags {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Layout taken from SO.css */
.tags > li {
  color: #566e76;
  background: #f7fdff;
  border: 1px solid #c0d4db;
  padding: .4em .5em;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin: 2px 2px 2px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 1;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tags > li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #f7d511;
}

.search {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  clear: both;
  margin: -0.5em 1em 1em 1em;
}

#mailConfig table {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

#mailConfig th {
  text-align: right;
}

#mailConfig td {
  text-align: left;
}

#userConfig {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.accountOption {
  border: 0.1em solid grey;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 0.6em;
  margin: 0.5em;
}

#footer {
  border-top: 0.1em solid black;
  margin-bottom: 0.2em;
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  direction: rtl;
  font-size: 0.8em;;
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>StackMailer</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/app.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <ul>
      <li>
        Home
      </li>
      <li>
        |
      </li>
      <li>
        Login
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="content">
    <h1>StackMailer</h1>
    <p id="intro">
      StackMailer allows you to receive periodic emails with the most popular questions on your favorite Stack Exchange site.
      <br /> Get started with your own schedule by selecting one of the Stack Exchange sites below.
    </p>

    <div id="settings">
      <div id="siteSelector">
        <h2>Pick a site</h2>
        <input type="text" placeholder="search" class="search" />

        <ul>
          <li>
            <p class="selectedSite">
              <strong>Stack Overflow</strong>
              <br />
              <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png" alt="Stack Overflow" />
            </p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>
              <strong>Server Fault</strong>
              <br />
              <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/serverfault/img/apple-touch-icon.png" alt="Server Fault" />
            </p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>
              <strong>Super User</strong>
              <br />
              <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/superuser/img/apple-touch-icon.png" alt="Stack Overflow" />
            </p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>
              <strong>Ask Ubuntu</strong>
              <br />
              <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/askubuntu/img/apple-touch-icon.png" alt="Stack Overflow" />
            </p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>
              <strong>Mathematics</strong>
              <br />
              <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/math/img/apple-touch-icon.png" alt="Stack Overflow" />
            </p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>
              <strong>Gaming</strong>
              <br />
              <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/gaming/img/apple-touch-icon.png" alt="Stack Overflow" />
            </p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div id="tagSelector">
        <h2>Select your favorite tags</h2>
        <input class="search" type="text" placeholder="search" />
        <div>
          <ul id="notSelectedTags" class="tags">
            <li>C#</li>
            <li>C++</li>
            <li>Java</li>
            <li>Javascript</li>
            <li>Python</li>
            <li>Unit-Testing</li>
            <li>.NET</li>
            <li>PHP</li>
            <li>COBOL</li>
            <li>SQL</li>
            <li>SQL-Server</li>
            <li>Ruby</li>
            <li>Perl</li>
            <li>VB.NET</li>
            <li>AngularJS</li>
            <li>MySQL</li>
            <li>SQL</li>
            <li>JQuery</li>
            <li>Android</li>
          </ul>

          <h3>Selected tags</h3>

          <ul id="selectedTags" class="tags">
            <li>C++11</li>
            <li>C</li>
            <li>Assembly</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="mailConfig">
        <h2>Configure your email settings</h2>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Frequency: </th>
            <td>
              <select>
                <option value="daily">Daily</option>
                <option value="weekly">Weekly</option>
                <option value="monthly">Monthly</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Time: </th>
            <td>
              <input type="time" value="07:00" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Amount of posts to show:</th>
            <td>
              <input type="number" value="10" max="50" min="1" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="userConfig">
      <button class="accountOption">
        <strong>Login</strong>
        <hr />
        <br />
        <br />
        <i>
          You will have the choice between several oAuth providers.
        </i>
      </button>

      <button class="accountOption">
        <strong>Register</strong>
        <hr />
        <br />
        <br />
        <i>
          Registering an account has the advantage that you can manage your subscriptions.
        </i>
      </button>

      <button class="accountOption">
        <strong>Anonymous</strong>
        <hr />
        <br />
        <br />
        <i>
          This means that you will not be able to change the subscription once it's finished.
        </i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    <em>Made by Jeroen Vannevel</em>. Visit me at <a href="http://www.vannevel.net" title="blog">my blog</a>.
  </div>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Semantic Markup

> ```
>   <div id="header">
>     <ul>
>       <li>
>         Home
>       </li>
>       <li>
>         |
>       </li>
>       <li>
>         Login
>       </li>
>     </ul>
>   </div>
> ```

I was going to suggest that you use a [header element](http://html5doctor.com/the-header-element/), but then I realized that this isn't a header, it's a [nav element](http://html5doctor.com/nav-element/). You should use the semantically appropriate elements whenever possible. `div`s are supposed to be for formatting purposes, when there is not a more semantically correct element available.

I like the choice of an unordered list for the links themselves though.

Now, *this* is a `<header>`, but you didn't add the tag.

> ```
> <h1>StackMailer</h1>
> <p id="intro">
>   StackMailer allows you to receive periodic emails with the most popular questions on your favorite Stack Exchange site.
>   <br /> Get started with your own schedule by selecting one of the Stack Exchange sites below.
> </p>
> ```

You may not use it for formatting *now*, but you may want to do so later. Create your markup correctly now, and you won't need to modify it later just to change the style (theoretically).

> ```
> <div id="siteSelector">
> ```

Again, this is HTML5, so use a semantic tag. In this case, this is a `<Section>`.

> The section element represents a generic document or application section…The section element is not a generic container element. When an element is needed only for styling purposes or as a convenience for scripting, authors are encouraged to use the div element instead. A general rule is that the section element is appropriate only if the element’s contents would be listed explicitly in the document’s outline.

I would put this in an outline, so I think the [section element](http://html5doctor.com/the-section-element/) is appropriate.

> ```
> <ul>
>   <li>
>     <p class="selectedSite">
>       <strong>Stack Overflow</strong>
>       <br />
>       <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png" alt="Stack Overflow" />
>     </p>
>   </li>
>   <li>
>     <p>
>       <strong>Server Fault</strong>
>       <br />
>       <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/serverfault/img/apple-touch-icon.png" alt="Server Fault" />
>     </p>
>   </li>
>   <li>
>     <p>
>       <strong>Super User</strong>
>       <br />
>       <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/superuser/img/apple-touch-icon.png" alt="Stack Overflow" />
>     </p>
>   </li>
> ```

I would discourage the use of `strong` and `br` here and prefer css for formatting purposes. (I know, easier said than done, particularly when you compare it to using the HTML tags.)

> ```
>     <table>
>       <tr>
>         <th>Frequency: </th>
>         <td>
>           <select>
>             <option value="daily">Daily</option>
>             <option value="weekly">Weekly</option>
>             <option value="monthly">Monthly</option>
>           </select>
>         </td>
>       </tr>
>       <tr>
>         <th>Time: </th>
>         <td>
>           <input type="time" value="07:00" />
>         </td>
>       </tr>
>       <tr>
>         <th>Amount of posts to show:</th>
>         <td>
>           <input type="number" value="10" max="50" min="1" />
>         </td>
>       </tr>
>     </table>
> ```

This isn't data, so a table isn't appropriate. This is where `div`s are appropriate.

> ```
>   <div id="footer">
>     <em>Made by Jeroen Vannevel</em>. Visit me at <a href="http://www.vannevel.net" title="blog">my blog</a>.
>   </div>
> ```

[Footer element...](http://html5doctor.com/the-footer-element-update/)

---

You had asked how you would replace the `strong` and `br` tags with CSS. I haven't worked the links out, but given some markup like this.

```
  <section id="siteSelector">
    <h2>Pick a site</h2>
    <input type="text" placeholder="search" class="search" />

    <ul>
      <li>
        <p class="selectedSite">
          Stack Overflow
          <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png" alt="Stack Overflow" />
        </p>
      <li>
          ...
```

You could format the list items for just this section with css (the part I haven't tested and you may need to tweak).

```
section.siteSelector ul {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

This should format just the lists within this particular list. The selector is read as `element.class anyChildElement`. More information can be found [in the manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors).

Comment: Interesting tags, I wasn't aware of them. A followup questions though: how exactly would I replace the `strong` and `br` tags with css?

Comment: *cough* with a `span` most likely... I've not totally sold myself that it would be better really. It's only really a benefit if you only want to change the formatting for *some* of the "important" elements but not others.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I added a quick (albeit untested and maybe wrong) example.